# My Beats Audio icon is no longer being displayed during playback

Tags: audio, htc-one-x

I bought an HTC One X and when I first started using it whenever I played audio I would have a little red Beats Audio icon shown in my notification bar. When you pulled the bar down it would list the item and say "Beats Audio enabled" and when you touched it, it would turn it off and on.

Recently it seems to have stopped being displayed. This is on all audio, so music from the htc music app, Youtube, and Deezer (a music streaming app).

Does anyone have any ideas on what's happened to it, if it's a known bug or if there is an obtuse setting hidden somewhere that I can try to see if I've turned it off by accident.

I have had a poke through the settings and can't see anything obvious. I am running TasKiller but I would assume that running an audio app would kick off the app.

Comment: I've submitted this issue to the HTC Support on the website, and I'll update with a response, if I get one.

Comment: Fyi - you don't need a task killer, it will just eat your battery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a reply from HTC technical support. Make of it what you will, I've asked the lady to clarify what she means as I don't understand her Engrish.

> Thank you for providing me with the additional details to enable me to
>   resolve your enquiry. It’s always our aim to ensure that our
>   customers’ issues are resolved first time and I’m sorry that this has
>   not happened in your case. Thank you for performing the steps outlined
>   in my previous email. I can confirm this has been removed in the 1.28
>   update for your device, Headset setting they have now are gone and
>   turns into “Other”. I am sorry for any inconvenience this may have
>   caused you. I look forward to hearing that this has resolved your
>   enquiry, to close your email or alternatively to reply to me please
>   follow the links below. You will shortly receive an email asking you
>   to submit your feedback, I would appreciate if you could take the time
>   to let me know about the level of service I have provided you with.

Apologies for the formatting, the HTC support portal strips everything! :facepalm:

So, in order to see the icon again.

1. You need to plugin a headset/headphones
2. Drag down your notifications bar, and hit 'Settings'
3. Click on 'Sound'
4. You'll notice the 'Sound enhancer' menu is now not greyed out
5. Tap this and you'll then get a choice of 'Sound enhancers' to use

Confirmed as working for me.

Comment: Mine didnt work it doesnt let me press sound enhancer

Comment: @lili You did plug in your headphones? ..and you do have a BeatsAudio handset?

Answer (score 2):

The htcbeatsnotify app is what shows the beats notification. If you disable it the notification doesn't show up.

Check that you have that app in all apps and it's not disabled.